# How do I find a byte of data located at a certain address from the disassembly of an object file?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, elf, disassembly, objdump

I have an object file `fact.o`, which is a binary file. To examine the disassembly of the object file, I ran the following command: `objdump -d fact.o`. I get the following output:

```
fact.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <factorial>:
   0:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
   5:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   a:   39 f8                   cmp    %edi,%eax
   c:   7f 08                   jg     16 <factorial+0x16>
   e:   0f af d0                imul   %eax,%edx
  11:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  14:   eb f4                   jmp    a <factorial+0xa>
  16:   89 d0                   mov    %edx,%eax
  18:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000019 <main>:
  19:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  1d:   bf 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%edi
  22:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  27 <main+0xe>
  27:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
  29:   be 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%esi
  2e:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  33:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  38:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  3d <main+0x24>
  3d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  42:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  46:   c3                      retq
```

I know the output is given in three columns: the instruction "address", the machine code (actual bytes stored in the object file), and the disassembly (assembly instructions interpreted from the machine code). My question is how can I find a byte of data located at a certain address? For example: how would I find the byte of data located at the address 0x10? I initially assumed it to be 0x89 from the output, but I'm pretty sure I'm incorrect. Any help is appreciated in helping me figure this out. I'm still trying to get used to assembly and any info will help me out a lot.

**Note**: I'm using gcc 9.2 if that is relevant for this question.

Comment: `readelf -a` shows file offset for sections.  Note that the addresses here are only *relative* to the start of the section, because this hasn't been linked at all, not even into a relocatable PIE (shared-object), where addresses would still be relative to the image base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should just take a bit of counting.

So for example finding `0x10`, first you find, on the leftmost column, the number closest to `0x10` but lower than that. Here, it's `0xe`:

```
   e:   0f af d0                imul   %eax,%edx
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Then we just count a bit. We know that at `0xe`, the byte is `0x0f`. 0xf will be `0xaf`, the byte right after `0x0f`, and 0x10 will be `0xd0`.

```
   e:   0f af d0                imul   %eax,%edx
         e  f 10
```

However, these addresses are only relative to the start of the section, not sure if that's what you want. See [Peter Cordes's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353129/how-do-i-find-a-byte-of-data-located-at-a-certain-address-from-the-disassembly-o/67353242#comment119049807_67353129).